# django oauth2 provider 401 after getting token

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I used [Django Oauth2 toolkit](http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_01.html) in my django app. my client is an angular web application and uses django api with oauth2.
it perfectly works in my localhost and every thing is ok but when i use application in server after success login and getting the access token when it requests another page with authentication the 401 error occures.

client is client.example.com and django api is on api.example.com.

please help me...

request token:

```
client_id:ePmICVI9Dwsb0eKCv8aMTKvq4Jnr7ewtFWFZGLEu
grant_type:password
username:mohammad
password:mz575451
client_secret:2RGeORI0eZbKFZX3gYtjGy
```

response:

```
{"expires_in": 36000, "token_type": "Bearer", "access_token": "yzKlTXuDLOZj5wGescfkNiejyYKhg2", "scope": "read write", "refresh_token": "JJp5Kxq3PcDQthwvSLxvfW2Ee5rLUE"}
```

Comment: maybe you want to post more of you passwords? You should change the urls. client.example.com  is not your site. change it to the actual name and change your passwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution!!!!!!! ^___^

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#apache-mod_wsgi-specific-configuration